# Not able to install Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2Client

Tags: .net, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, entity-framework-6, xero-api

I am using .net entity framework version 6.3.0.
I am trying to install Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2Client package into my project.
When trying to install getting "**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2Client 0.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.            0** " error.
Can anyone please let me know how to fix this and install?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? I couldn't install in VS2013, even with the minimum .net 4.6.1 targeting pack installed (and a few later ones), but it installed straight away in VS2019.